# Using Adapters with a Facade

Tags: design-patterns

My architecture previously was using a facade to perform a number of tasks through a simple set of methods. Something like:

```
startComputer(...)
shutdownComputer(...)
```

As I expand the application, I have the need to translate multiple types of input to the facade itself. Let's say that in the past `startComputer` took 6 parameters, and in the new architecture it takes some sort of parseable string input, and in another case, some base-64 encoded mess. Basically, across the board, I want to access the same sub-system through high-level commands, but define interfaces that take all sorts of formats.

I get confused when I start thinking about adapters vs. facades -- maybe especially because people are always delineating the differences. In this case, what I essentially want (I think) is to make adapters to support various inputs while keeping the facade as is. In this case, the facade is the adaptee.

Does this make sense or is there a better way?

Comment: An easy way to remember the distinction: Adapters exist purely to take one interface and allow it to wrap/present itself as another, whereas facades act as a high level simplification for a more complicated system.  One is a necessity, the other is a nicety :)

Comment: I may not have phrased this correctly -- What I'm proposing is that I use both at the same time to accomplish both objectives -- one interface wrapping another one that happens to simplify a more complicated system.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

sounds like you want your facade to use the "command" pattern to define it's parameters
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Command_pattern

Comment: Maybe... but I would still need to convert all varying input into some sort of Command object.

Comment: im sugesting that the methods on your facade take commands as parameters.  callers of the facade can choose which type of command to create and pass in

Comment: But wouldn't I still need an adapter to convert all the various types of input into the unified Command object? 3 different classes want to be able to send the same Command but have to be created from different input.

Comment: you can have 3 different subclasses of Command but facade would take the base class as a parameter